# manual new line in QGraphicsText Item

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

i created a editable text class inheriting QGraphicsTextitem and with setTextIntraction flag im allowing the user to enter the text in the QGraphicsTextItem.

now i want to add a new line manually when the graphicsTextitem width exceeds the viewport width . but i cant find the relevant way to manually  add a new line when the textWidth exceeds the width of the viewport.

i managed to shift the text left and up as

```
QGraphicsView *view = scene()->views()[0];
    QRect viewport_rect(0, 0, view->viewport()->width(), view->viewport()->height());
    QRectF visible_scene_rect = view->mapToScene(viewport_rect).boundingRect();

    qreal sceneRightEnd = visible_scene_rect.right();
    qreal sceneBottom = visible_scene_rect.bottom();


    QPointF textItemRight = mapToScene( now.bottomRight() ) ;
    if(textItemRight.x() >= sceneRightEnd)
    {
        this->moveBy(sceneRightEnd - textItemRight.x(), 0);
    }

    if(textItemRight.y() >= sceneBottom )
    {
        this->moveBy( 0, ( sceneBottom - textItemRight.y() ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of your text item by calling:

```
QGraphicsTextItem::setTextWidth(qreal width)
```

The default width is -1 which causes the text not to be broken into multiple lines.

If you set a width and the actual text is wider than the specified width then it will be broken into multiple lines.